# Alert function impossible to add

Tags: pine-script

I got a v2 script from a user on tradingview that ends with the code below.
I have 2 problems to fix.
First of all, I cant seem to add an alert function no matter all the tutorials I read.
Second, the strategy seems to repaint. Please help, need to figure these things out.
The only thing I personally added are the last 2 rows.

```
 buying = l3_0 > threshold ? true : l3_0 < -threshold ? false : buying[1]

hline(0, title="base line")
//bgcolor(l3_0 > 0.0014 ? green : l3_0 < -0.0014 ? red : gray, transp=20)
bgcolor(buying ? green : red, transp=20)
plot(l3_0, color=silver, style=area, transp=75)
plot(l3_0, color=aqua, title="prediction")

longCondition = buying
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
shortCondition = buying != true
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
// Alerts
alertcondition(longCondition, title='buy', message='buy asset')
alertcondition(shortCondition, title='Sell', message='sell asset')
```

Answer (score 0):

alertcondition only work in **study**. No in strategy.

Try this:

```
CountCond = 0
CountCond := buying ? 1 :
     not buying ? -1 :
     nz(CountCond[1])

longCondition = CountCond == 1 and CountCond[1] == -1
shortCondition = CountCond == -1 and CountCond[1] == 1

plotshape(longCondition ? close: na, text="Long", location = location.abovebar)
plotshape(shortCondition ? close: na, text="Short", location = location.abovebar)

// Alerts
alertcondition(longCondition, title='buy', message='buy asset')
alertcondition(shortCondition, title='Sell', message='sell asset')
```

Comment: Great thanks. alerts are working now.



I've been trying to add buy and sell symbols but 2 problems occur.
1. Plots are located in the indicator legend and not by the candels
2. They appear continously rather than 1 time. any suggestions?

plotshape (buy, style=shape.circle, color=green, size=size.small)
plotshape (sell, style=shape.circle, color=red, size=size.small)

Comment: 1. I call it "Condition Counter". Try the code I just modified

Comment: 2. Need [location parameter] (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/annotations/Plotting_shapes_chars_and_arrows.html#plotshape)